# Is $f(A_1\bigcup A_2) =f(A_1)\bigcup f(A_2)$ true for countably many $A_i$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I was unable to think about The proof or counterexample of this identity when I was attempting a question.

So, I am asking for help here.

> Suppose $A_i$ $i \in \mathbb{N}$ are all non-empty sets , I have proved that $f(A_1 \bigcup A_2 ) = f(A_1) \bigcup f(A_2) $. using mathematical induction the result can be proved for  finite number of $A_i$ but is the result true when $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

Why or why not?

Comment: True even for uncountable unions. Just check that each side is contained in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on Kavi Rama Murthy's comment, here is a full proof of the formula
$$
f\Bigl(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i\Bigr) = \bigcup_{i \in I} f(A_i) \qquad (1)
$$
Let $L$ and $R$ be the left and right hand side of $(1)$, respectively.
If $x \in L$, then $x = f(s)$ for some $s \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$. Then there exists $i \in I$ such that $s \in A_i$. It follows that $f(s) \in f(A_i)$ and hence $x = f(s) \in R$. Thus $L \subseteq R$. To prove the opposite inclusion, consider some $x \in R$. Then there exists $i \in I$ such that $x \in f(A_i)$. Consequently, $x = f(s)$ for some $s \in A_i$. It follows that $s \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ and thus $x = f(s) \in L$. Thus $R = L$.

Observe that no induction is needed for this proof.